# mysql cannot connect:invalid settings with other errors

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to access my database on phpmyadmin but I can't access to that page. I am getting a lot of different errors and I tried a lot of different solutions but it didn't work.

I tried changing the password in config.inc.php file and also the auth_type but nothing happened.

I also tried editing it through cmd with the commands resetroot.bat

[this is the screenshot of the page I'm seeing [click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BU1aU.jpg)

Comment: You need to change your authentication type in MySQL, as PHP does not support authentication via sha2 yet.

Comment: may ik how to do that?

Comment: I think you need to reinstall mysql again. Might be your problem would solved.